Dot Net Core IFormFile giving null while uploading some (not all) PDF and DOCX files
I am working on ASP .Net Core for file uploading by using IFormFile. However, IFormFile is null while uploading some (not all) PDF and DOCX files.
In some cases, the code works fine.
The file is clearly shown while debugging in JavaScript, but after POST IFormFile shoes NULL.
Even the no SIZE issue
ERROR I GOT - net::ERR_FAILED
I used the below code for uploading files.
Kindly help to solve the issue.
C#:
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file){

// Here file is getting NULL in some cases but working fine for some cases (uploading PDF &   DOCX)

}

JAVASCRIPT:
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'URL', true);
try {
    xhr.onload = function () {
        debugger;
        alert(xhr.status);
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            
        } else {
           
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
} catch (error) {
    alert(error);
}`


I remember dealing with something similar, but ended up not using automatic binding altogether. Which files work and which don't? Could be a size thing.

any errors show from that script?  You might check request in backend like:  IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];  If there's always one file.  Hard to say without the fail case...  Is anti-forgery on?  You might simplify the xmlrequest using a standard fetch and creating formData() using the whole form.   (get the  element and send that to new formData(formElement)...)

you may also want to run some checks in your javascript... it depends on what event fires the POST.   Ex:  if (fileInput.files) {...}

The file is clearly shown while debugging in JavaScript, but after POST  IFormFile shoes NULL.
Even the no SIZE issue
ERROR - POST MYURL net::ERR_FAILED

You need to isolate the fail case... is it possibly a file size issue?  (files larger than X cause the error?)

Thanks Browsermator!!!!
Below code solve my issue
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
options.Conventions
.AddPageApplicationModelConvention("/PAGE NAME", model =>{
model.Filters.Add(new RequestSizeLimitAttribute(52428800));
});
});
